# OkHttp 3 and HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, okhttp

I am a bit confused about how to upgrade OkHttp to v3.0.0 while keeping our code that uses `HttpURLConnection`.
Our current dependencies are:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.0'
```

The changelog states:

> The Apache HTTP client and HttpURLConnection APIs are deprecated. They continue to work as they always have, but we're moving everything to the new OkHttp 3 API. The okhttp-apache and okhttp-urlconnection modules should be only be used to accelerate a transition to OkHttp's request/response API. These deprecated modules will be dropped in an upcoming OkHttp 3.x release.

Unfortunately it is not clear to me what "we're moving everything to the new OkHttp 3 API" means.

I tried to depend on `com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.0` but that doesn't exist.

Should I keep `com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.0` and upgrade only `com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp` to 3.0.0?
Or does this sentence mean that depending only on `com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp` should work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I tried to depend on `com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.0` but that doesn't exist.

The names were updated as well. It is now

```
com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.0
```

NOte the `okhttp3` instead of `okhttp`.

For more information on the reasoning behind this, see Jake Wharton (the author)'s blog post on **Java Interoperability Policy for Major Version Updates** here:

https://jakewharton.com/java-interoperability-policy-for-major-version-updates/

See [jCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.squareup.okhttp3%3Aokhttp-urlconnection/view#files/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.0.0).

Comment: Doh!  The funny thing is I saw this, but then my brain decided to black it out ;)  Thanks!

Comment: Except now I have this weird problem: `com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lokhttp3/Address;`   [edit].. which I fixed like this, but this is weird: `compile ('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.0') { exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3' }`

Comment: @BoD new problem -> new question

Comment: I ended up opening a ticket here about this second problem: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2243

Comment: Using `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.1` seems to fix the github issue.